# LM358 OPAMP non inverting amplifier DC errors

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, dc, error

Trying to amplify IR sensor 40mV DC output using LM358 noninverting amplifier circuit.

[image: opamp circuit]

Selected resistance as R1 2.2K and feedback resistance, R2 51K. Got output voltage 0.8V. Measured output voltage by changing resistance values R1 to 1K and R2 to upto 1M, but output voltage didn't get above 0.8V. Supply voltage of opamp is 5V.

How can I get the output voltage of opamp above 1.5V?

Comment: What's the sensor you are using *(Brand, model and a datasheet, if possible)*?

Comment: TCRT5000 IR sensor

Comment: [Sensor data sheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83760/tcrt5000.pdf).

Comment: The sensor is a reflective sensor with transistor output. I'm curious, how did you get 40mV output? You should post the full schematic with sensor/detector part. Maybe you are doing something wrong at detection side *(e.g. getting the output directly from the collector-emitter without any pull-up/pull-down resistors)* and maybe that's why the opamp is giving constantly 800mV output.

Comment: 0.8V constant means, the voltage not changes with resistance values(feedback resistance)..but when the sensor detects, the output of opamp changes to mV..otherwise the output will be 0.8V. I would like to know, why the opamp output voltage not changes with resistance value?

Comment: yes, i have tested without connecting pullup resistor in the collector.now i connected collector of transistor to 3.3V through  10K resistor.I tested this sensor in a room, the voltage across the collector and Gnd is high voltage (above 2.5V) and if there is any obstacles (when i showing my hand ) the voltage reduced to below 1voltage..But when i tested this sensor in daylight without any obstacles the voltage is below 500mV..Does the daylight affect the sensor reading?

Comment: What power supply voltages are you using on your op amp?

Answer (score 1):

> *Selected Resistance as R1 2.2K and feedback resistance, R2 51K.*

The input offset voltage of the LM358 is typically 2 mV but can be as high as 5 mV and if you ignore the input signal (set it to 0 mV as a thought experiment), the output voltage is: -

$$\text{±2 mV}\cdot\left(1 + \dfrac{\text{51 kohm}}{\text{2.2 kohm}}\right) = \text{±48 mV}$$

So that's a pretty big basic error given that a 40 mV input signal is meant to be amplified to 967 mV (a ±5% error). That is for a typical input offset voltage of 2 mV and, of course will be 2.5 times worse at extremes.

> *Measured output voltage by changing resistance values R1 to 1K and R2
> to upto 1M*

Now the gain is about a 1000 and the input offset of ±2 mV could produce an output all on its own of ±2 volts. So at one extreme, the output could be 2 volt low and at the other extreme, the output could be 2 volts high. Somewhere in between these numbers is where the output offset voltage could be.

<sub>If your LM358 is powered from 5 volts and 0 volt then clearly it cannot produce a negative output voltage and so the output may "clamp" close to 0 volts.</sub>

Do you see the problem: -

$$\color{red}{\boxed{\text{You need an op-amp with a much better input offset voltage}}}$$

There may be other problems too but this one is glaring.

Comment: when I tested with R1 1K and R2 1M, the ouput voltage is .8V. Output voltage not varying with respect to resistance value.                                                   The output of opamp varies from 0.8V to mv range, when IR sensor ouput changes..

Comment: @SUMYPOULOSE Nothing surprises me when using an LM358 (or LM324) in this type of circuit. Offset voltage can be negative too. You also need to account for \$IR\$ losses in the cable and bad grounds. You need to be very careful not to introduce unintentional offsets. It's easy to do. The LM358 is a bad choice for this type of measurement.

Comment: Can you suggest which opamp is better for mV input?               you told that without any input ,will got an output voltage of 2 volts when resistance values as R1- 1K and R2- 1M. but i got only 0.8V..why didnt i get 2 volts?

Comment: There are many mechanisms at work and to understand your exact setup is beyond the scope of remote help through this site. I can only repeat what I said in my answer - the input offset problem is glaring AND there may be other problems related to your set-up i.e. IR volt drops, bad op-amp supplies, sensor output impedance (and op-amp bias currents), imprecise measurements etc etc.. I can't recommend an op-amp because I know nothing about what you can purchase or where you can purchase from or your budget - you choose one and come back with a new question.

Comment: Measured output voltage by changing resistance values R1 to 1K and R2 to upto 1M

Now the gain is about a 1000 and the input offset of 2 mV could produce an output all on its own of 2 volts.                    Didnt get this 2 volts..

Comment: You don't appear to be listening @SUMYPOULOSE - the op-amp is unsuitable.

Comment: I tested circuit using LM358 with R1 2.2K and feedback resistor R2 100K..I got the output voltage 1.8V when IR not detected  and mV output when IR detected..I got the expected ouput.. Thanks for your inputs...

Comment: @SUMYPOULOSE if you are happy with an answer please consider formally accepting it.